# How to add data to dictionary in for loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to know how can i update a dictionary with some results in a for loop.

Currently, i have something like this :

```
some_dict = {}
result = call_to_some_method(some_data)
some_dict.update(json.loads(result))
```

I am now changing the code as follows:

```
some_dict = {}
for i in ["cat","cat2","zeta"]:
    result = call_to_some_method(some_data)
    ## Update the result for each iteration
```

can someone help, such that in the end I am having a dictionary as previous to return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is the below:

```
some_dict = {}
for i in ["cat","cat2","zeta"]:
    result = call_to_some_method(i)
    some_dict[i] = result # This updates the dictionary
```